# OData Client Code Generator, create and update containment entities

Tags: c#, .net, odata, asp.net-web-api2

Software used:

- ASP.NET Web API 2.2
- OData v4.0
- OData Client for .NET (v 6.11)

I have created an OData endpoint by following [this](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/odata-support-in-aspnet-web-api/odata-v4/create-an-odata-v4-endpoint) tutorial:

The client app uses the [OData Client Code Generator](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/odata-support-in-aspnet-web-api/odata-v4/create-an-odata-v4-client-app) for reading data from the OData endpoint.

The model which is used contains an Order entity with linked OrderLine entities.
Reading Order entities from the OData endpoint is possible by sending a GET request to:

```
https://server/Orders
```

For reading the Orderline entities I have configured an Containment. Reading a orderlines is possible by sending a GET request to this Uri.

```
https://server/Orders(1)/OrderLines
```

From my client app I can send these request using OData Client Code Generator. Creating / updating / deleting order entities works like a charm.

Reading orderline entities also works like a charm:

```
var orderLines = _serviceClient.Orders.ByKey(orderId).OrderLines.Execute();
```

I have created OData EndPoint methods for creating / updating / deleting an OrderLine entities, but the problem is that I cannot find a way to create new OrderLine entities for an order using the Client Code Generator. I also don't know how to update or delete an OrderLine entity.

Any suggestions how to send POST / PUT / DELETE request's to the containment methods using the Client Code Generator?

Comment: I have the exact same scenario - did you find a solution for this? The only reasonable solution I see is creating an action to handle each create, update, and delete, but I don't want to do that If I can avoid it...

Comment: I found a way to do POST and PUT/PATCH, which is what I needed for my use, so I posted an answer below. I don't have a solution for DELETE yet.

Answer (score 1):

After some investigation and testing, it looks like the `AddRelatedObject(object source, string sourceProperty, object target)` method on the `DataServiceContext` class is what you want for POST, and the `UpdateRelatedObject(object source, string sourceProperty, object target)` method is the one you want for PUT/PATCH. I don't see one for DELETE specifically, so I'm not sure how to accomplish that.

But here's an example of how to POST:

```
var order = _serviceClient.Orders.ByKey(orderId).GetValue();
var newOrderLine = new OrderLine()
{
    ...
};

_serviceClient.AddRelatedObject(order, nameof(order.OrderLines), newOrderLine);
_serviceClient.SaveChanges();
```

Here's the relevant doc links:

- AddRelatedObject: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.odata.client.dataservicecontext.addrelatedobject?view=odata-client-7.0
- UpdatedRelatedObject: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.odata.client.dataservicecontext.updaterelatedobject?view=odata-client-7.0

Answer (score -4):

If you look at http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/odata-support-in-aspnet-web-api/odata-v3/calling-an-odata-service-from-a-net-client you can see how to send these requests.

**How to POST:**
"To add a new entity to an entity set, call AddToEntitySet, where EntitySet is the name of the entity set. For example, AddToProducts adds a new Product to the Products entity set. When you generate the proxy, WCF Data Services automatically creates these strongly-typed AddTo methods."

**How to UPDATE:**
"To update an entity, call the UpdateObject method.

The update is performed when you call SaveChanges. By default, WCF sends an HTTP MERGE request. The PatchOnUpdate option tells WCF to send an HTTP PATCH instead.

If you want to replace the entire entity (PUT semantics), specify the ReplaceOnUpdate option. This causes WCF to send an HTTP PUT request."

Example: container.SaveChanges(SaveChangesOptions.ReplaceOnUpdate);

**How to DELETE:**
"To delete an entity, call DeleteObject"

**GET** and **PATCH** are also described on this page.

Comment: Did you even read his question? OData v4 is a requirement. You linked OData v3 documentation and just copied and pasted some text. OData v3 doesn't even support containment...